# How to convert .rst files to .md?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

I have a doc as an .rst file, how is it possible to easily and fully convert it to .md? 
I found a tool named pandoc, but it does not correctly convert the file. It works like

```
pandoc about.rst -s -o about.md
```

Are there any available tools?

Comment: What specifically does not convert correctly?

Comment: I have warnings like [pandoc warning] ignoring unknown directive: toctree "source" , and some files lost part of content.

Comment: Markdown supports is only a limited subset of HTML. Therefore, it cannot represent everything from other markup languages. If you want to convert to Markdown, then the source document can only contain features supported by Markdown. There may be workarounds, but for us to help, you will need to provide specific information regarding the errors you are receiving and what input is generating those errors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First the [syntax for using pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#synopsis) is:

```
pandoc [options] [input-file]…
```

You did this:

```
pandoc [input-file] [options]…
```

To correct it, do this:

```
pandoc -s -o about.md about.rst
```

As @Waylan mentioned in their comment, Markdown supports a small subset of reStructuredText features. Pandoc, however, provides an [extended version of Markdown](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) which can be enabled through extensions. This might resolve some of your errors, but not others.

Ultimately you will need to edit your question to improve it (don't reply with a comment) with the full error stack for further assistance.

Comment: The first file name is the output file. This is confusing because you write : `pandoc [options] [input-file]`.

It is this way:  `pandoc -o [output-file] [input-file]`

Comment: @FranzHolzinger `-o` *is* an option. Without specifying that option, output goes to stdout by default.

Comment: In my experience the output needs editing in order to be compatible with the GitHub-supported subset of markdown